# I have a bicycle frame that is not stamped and I can't figure out how to identify the brand of it

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Serial number EY121000136 it's a 20 inch bmx bicycle

Comment: Read the suggested link from Daniel.  Sadly the serial number can only be useful if you already know the manufacturer, AND they had a decent records system AND they look it up for you.   It is nothing like an automotive VIN.

Comment: You could try adding a clear and well-lit photo of the bike from its right-hand side.  And also a second photo of any particularly unique feature that might be recognisable.   A head tube badge or decal, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

By checking in [the database of stolen bikes](https://bikeindex.org/bikes?serial=EY12&stolenness=all) my guess is that it is a Raleigh something. A picture would help, though, to confirm this guess.

On top of the reason of the questions being closed will probably help you answering yourself your question.